# Incremental build support for output directory considering added files

Tags: gradle, incremental-build

The Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) tells this:

> Note that if a task has an output directory specified, any files added to that directory since the last time it was executed are ignored and will NOT cause the task to be out of date. This is so unrelated tasks may share an output directory without interfering with each other. If this is not the behaviour you want for some reason, consider using TaskOutputs.upToDateWhen(groovy.lang.Closure)

Question: How does the solution with upToDateWhen look like (so that added files are considered). The main problem is that one has to access the build cache to retrieve the output directory content hash the last time the task ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly or why you mention the build cache. I assume you are not aware that the predicates added with `upToDateWhen()` are considered **in addition** to any other up-to-date checks like the ones added with `TaskOutputs.dir()`?

Take the following sample task:

```
task foo {
    def outDir = file('out')
    outputs.dir(outDir)
    outputs.upToDateWhen { outDir.listFiles().length == 1 }
    doLast {
       new File(outDir, 'foo.txt') << 'whatever'
    }
}
```

As long as there is only a single file in the output directory (as configured via `upToDateWhen`) *and* the file produced by the task (`out/foo.txt`) isn’t changed after the task has run, the task will be up-to-date. If you change/remove the file created by the task in the output directory or if you add further files to the output directory, then the task will run again.

---

Updated answer as per the updated question from the comments:

```
task foo {
    def outDir = file('out')

    /* sample task action: */
    doFirst {
        def numOutFiles = new Random().nextInt(5)
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOutFiles; i++) {
            new File(outDir, "foo${i}.txt") << 'whatever'
        }
    }

    /* up-to-date checking configuration: */
    def counterFile = new File(buildDir, 'counterFile.txt')
    outputs.dir(outDir)
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        counterFile.isFile() \
          && counterFile.text as Integer == countFiles(outDir)
    }
    doLast {
        counterFile.text = countFiles(outDir)
    }
}

def countFiles(def dir) {
    def result = 0
    def files = dir.listFiles()
    if (files != null) {
        files.each {
            result++
            if (it.isDirectory()) {
                result += countFiles(it)
            }
        }
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: The logic in upToDateWhen would have to check the exact content in outDir against the exact content the last time the task finished. Do you know how to access the latter?

Comment: What do you mean by “would have to check”, is that some business requirement of yours? Note that Gradle _automatically_ checks the up-to-date status of all files produced by your task (or `foo` in my example) in the output directory. You only need `upToDateWhen` for any **additional** checks required by your business logic.

Comment: Clarification of the question: Provide a task which you can give an output directory such that the task is up-to-date exactly when the content of the output directory did not change at all. More precisely, let A be the content of the output directory when the task finished the last time and let B the content of the output directory just now before the task wants to run. Then the task runs only if A is equal to B.

Comment: @WernerThumann: I have updated my answer as per your updated question. The part of your comment starting with “More precisely” is actually the opposite of the part before; I assume you are after the interpretation from the first part. Otherwise just negate the predicate in the `upToDateWhen` closure of my updated code sample.

Comment: You're right the last sentence should be "A is not equal to B". Thank you for your solution. However it I'd like to reuse the build cache from Gradle instead of simulating a new one by creating the counter file, that's why I created this question. But I already assume that this is just not possible, and therefore I accept your answer as long as there is no better solution.